# Efficient way to calculate number of foreign keys in second table and display it with rows from first table - PHP - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables `tablea` and `tableb` like below;

**tablea**

```
+--------+-------+-------+-------+------+
|   fa   |   fb  |  fc   |  fd   |  fe  |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+------+
|  col1  |  f11  |  f12  |  f13  |  x1  |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+------+
|  col2  |  f21  |  f22  |  f23  |  x2  |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+------+
|  col3  |  f31  |  f32  |  f33  |  x3  |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+------+
|  col4  |  f41  |  f42  |  f43  |  x4  |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+------+
```

**tableb**

```
+--------+-------+-------+-------+------+
|  tbba  |  tbbb |  tbbc |  tbbd | tbbe |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+------+
|  cola  |  fa1  |  fa2  |  fa3  |  x1  |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+------+
|  colb  |  fb1  |  fb2  |  fb3  |  x1  |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+------+
|  colc  |  fc1  |  fc2  |  fc3  |  x1  |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+------+
|  cold  |  fd1  |  fd2  |  fd3  |  x2  |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+------+
|  cole  |  fe1  |  fe2  |  fe3  |  x2  |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+------+
|  colf  |  ff1  |  ff2  |  ff3  |  x3  |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+------+
|  colg  |  fg1  |  fg2  |  fg3  |  x3  |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+------+
|  colh  |  fh1  |  fh2  |  fh3  |  x3  |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+------+
|  coli  |  fi1  |  fi2  |  fi3  |  x3  |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+------+
|  colj  |  fj1  |  fj2  |  fj3  |  x4  |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+------+
```

I want to generate a table like;

```
+--------+-------+-----+
|  col1  |  f11  |  3  |
+--------+-------+-----+
|  col2  |  f21  |  2  |
+--------+-------+-----+
|  col3  |  f31  |  4  |
+--------+-------+-----+
|  col4  |  f41  |  1  |
+--------+-------+-----+
```

The number denotes the times where entry in `fe` field of `tablea` appears in `tableb`. Currently, I am fetching all rows from the `tablea`, and in each loop, I use another query to get number of rows in `tableb`, using `tablea`'s `fe` field. Thus, I have 1 main query, and 4 sub queries. Is there any efficient way like join or something?

Thank you

Comment: Can you just join the two tables on fe=tbbe and group by fa, fb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.fa , a.fb , COUNT( b.tbbe) 
FROM  tablea a
LEFT JOIN tableb b ON a.fe = b.tbbe
GROUP BY a.fa
```

Comment: why we use `GROUP BY a.fa `?

Comment: Otherwise you will get only one row. This is to get count per a.fa.