# How to calculate number of foreign keys in second table with a condition and display it with rows from first table - PHP - MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables `tablea` and `tableb` like below;

**tablea**

```
+--------+-------+-------+-------+------+
|   fa   |   fb  |  fc   |  fd   |  fe  |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+------+
|  col1  |  f11  |  f12  |  f13  |  x1  |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+------+
|  col2  |  f21  |  f22  |  f23  |  x2  |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+------+
|  col3  |  f31  |  f32  |  f33  |  x3  |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+------+
|  col4  |  f41  |  f42  |  f43  |  x4  |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+------+
```

**tableb**

```
+--------+-------+-------+------+------+
|  tbba  |  tbbb |  tbbc | tbbd | tbbe |
+--------+-------+-------+------+------+
|  cola  |  fa1  |  fa2  |  0   |  x1  |
+--------+-------+-------+------+------+
|  colb  |  fb1  |  fb2  |  0   |  x1  |
+--------+-------+-------+------+------+
|  colc  |  fc1  |  fc2  |  1   |  x1  |
+--------+-------+-------+------+------+
|  cold  |  fd1  |  fd2  |  1   |  x2  |
+--------+-------+-------+------+------+
|  cole  |  fe1  |  fe2  |  1   |  x2  |
+--------+-------+-------+------+------+
|  colf  |  ff1  |  ff2  |  0   |  x3  |
+--------+-------+-------+------+------+
|  colg  |  fg1  |  fg2  |  1   |  x3  |
+--------+-------+-------+------+------+
|  colh  |  fh1  |  fh2  |  1   |  x3  |
+--------+-------+-------+------+------+
|  coli  |  fi1  |  fi2  |  0   |  x3  |
+--------+-------+-------+------+------+
|  colj  |  fj1  |  fj2  |  0   |  x4  |
+--------+-------+-------+------+------+
```

I want to generate a table like;

```
+--------+-------+-----+
|  col1  |  f11  |  1  |
+--------+-------+-----+
|  col2  |  f21  |  2  |
+--------+-------+-----+
|  col3  |  f31  |  2  |
+--------+-------+-----+
|  col4  |  f41  |  0  |
+--------+-------+-----+
```

This is the number of foreign keys in tablea `tablea.fe` in tableb `tableb.tbbe`, and with `tableb.tbbd` field having value `1`. I had a query like;

```
SELECT a.fa , a.fb , COUNT( b.tbbe) 
FROM  tablea a
LEFT JOIN tableb b ON a.fe = b.tbbe
GROUP BY a.fa
```

But this counts all foreign keys without checking the status of `tableb.tbbd` field. How can I create this table?

You may refer my another question here [Efficient way to calculate number of foreign keys in second table and display it with rows from first table - PHP - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30746838/efficient-way-to-calculate-number-of-foreign-keys-in-second-table-and-display-it)

Thank you.

Comment: This is not clear to me, I can't see where you're getting your counts from. How did you get 1 for (col1, f11)?

Comment: `col1` and `f11` are values from fields `fa` and `fb` of tablea. `1` represents, the foreign key `x1` appears 3 times in `tableb`, but when we consider `tableb.tbbd` field, it becomes `1`, since in two out of three rows, `tbbd` field is 0.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clearing that up. I have given an answer and SQL Fiddle example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake in your query is simply that you never add a condition to also join where `b.tbbd = 1`. You can add it like this:

```
SELECT a.fa, a.fb, COUNT(b.tbbe)
FROM tablea a
LEFT JOIN tableb b ON a.fe = b.tbbe AND b.tbbd = 1
GROUP BY a.fa, a.fb;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/208bd3/1) example.

Comment: Note that it is good practice to group by all non-aggregate columns in your query. In this example, notice how I grouped by (a.fa, a.fb) and not just a.fa.

Answer (score 0):

If `b.tbbd` is a only ever 0 or 1 then you can use `SUM()` instead of `COUNT()` which will exclude the rows where tbbd = 0.

```
SELECT a.fa , a.fb , SUM( b.tbbe) 
FROM  tablea a
LEFT JOIN tableb b ON a.fe = b.tbbe
GROUP BY a.fa
```

If `b.tbbd` can be any number but you're just looking for the rows where it equals 1 then just add an `AND` to your `ON` clause

```
SELECT a.fa , a.fb , COUNT( b.tbbe) 
FROM  tablea a
LEFT JOIN tableb b ON a.fe = b.tbbe AND b.tbbd = 1
GROUP BY a.fa
```